# Ignore code in excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following line of VBA code.

```
If IsEmpty(sheetname.Range("K" & i)) = False Or sheetname.Range("K" & i) > 0 Then
```

I need the If statement to return false if there is a formula in the cell but not an actual value. For example, if you open the sheet and select a cell in the K column you will see this formula in the cell`=IF(OR(J9<>0,G9<>0),-J9+G9,"")`. Or, if the `IsEmpty` method is not the best way to go then another suggestion.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: HasFormula Property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195416(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: You may use the Len function to check for empty string `If Len(sheetname.Range("K" & i)) > 0 Then`

Comment: @Santosh Good answer. Put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @ooo +1 Good answer. I like it when links are left with answers. I almost used it but Santosh's answer worked better for me. Thanks!

Comment: If using IfEmpty it's usually `If IsEmpty()` or `If Not IsEmpty()` rather than testing for true/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use len function to check for empty string

> If Len(sheetname.Range("K" & i)) > 0 Then

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Range.HasFormula` function:

```
If sheetname.Range("K" & i).HasFormula = False
```